# how do I access Wifi on xubuntu 14.04? It has something to do with with the proprietary drivers stopping me

Tags: wireless, 14.04, dell, ethernet, proprietary

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Latitude D620, I do not know what kind of wifi card I have but I do know I have one. When I turn it on Xubuntu doesn't attempt to search for wireless networks, instead saying the ethernet is offline. I know it has something to do with the proprietary drivers that were previously installed due to this being a company owned computer. What can I do to make Xubuntu attempt to connect or even recognize the wifi around?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: At very least, please post the information listed for "Network controller" from the output of the command `lspci -v`